# Generating Checksum for Java Object

Tags: java

I have a Java class that implements Serializable:

```
Class A implements Serializable {
    public String name;
    int contact;
}
```

I store this Java object in mongodb. How can I generate a checksum for this Java object?

```
public String generateChecksum throws Exception(A object){
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
     oos.writeObject(object);

     MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
     byte[] thedigest = md.digest(baos.toByteArray());
     String hex =  DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(thedigest);
     System.out.println(hex);
}
```

I am getting a

> Null Pointer Exception at oos.writeObject(object).

Is there a better way to do this??

Comment: `I am getting a Null Pointer Exception at oos.writeObject(object).` - are you sure that object you are trying to compute checksum for is not null? Can you provide full stacktrace?

Comment: Your checksum  code works. It must be a null object.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have specific requirements for the checksum, the simplest approach is to use a hashCode.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, contact);
}

public static String hashCodeString(Object a) {
    return Integer.toHexString(a.hashCode());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that your code does not compile.

```
Class A implements Serializable {


public String generateChecksum throws Exception(A object){
```

Comment: Most likely the OP is running an old version of the code with a bug in it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Whatever the reason, we don't appear to have the source code of what is being run. (I'm being a little bit cheeky - I generally don't bother attempting to compile the code I post in answers.)